# What does the N stand for in the keyboard shortcut for Chrome's Incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, terminology

The shortcut for Chrome's Incognito mode is <kbd>Control</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>N</kbd>. Why an "N"?

I know in Firefox, it's <kbd>Control</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd> and the P stands for "Private" (browsing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> is New Window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> is New Incognito Window.

They've used the same, well known shortcut for New Window and added <kbd>Shift</kbd> to allow it to do something slightly different.